# coc.nvim selected suggestion background color

Tags: coc.nvim

The background color of the currently-selected-suggestion does not contrast enough with the text to be readable. How can this be fixed?

Setting Pmenu and/or PmenuSel in does NOT improve the situation, as neither change this background color.

.exrc is EMPTY (so no color changes by me)

Using default terminal program, without changing any colors.

Using vim (8.2) on MacOS Monterey (12.5) with the M1 (arm64) cpu.

Same issue on iTerm2 using custom color scheme, so it's not the terminal's fault, I don't think.

[image: Selected Suggestion]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same problem on my side, after trial and error using

```
    hi CocMenuSel ctermbg=darkgrey ctermfg=yellow
    hi CocSearch ctermfg=blue
```

in `~/.vimrc`
produces a reasonable contrast on my side with on a Mac with  white terminal bg.
Use `:hi` to scroll thru the color suggestions of vim to see the possible names and color appearance.